# How to create a custom property like adding image on a button in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a custom UI editor. The editor allows us to place background images on buttons. But, unlike the VS editor, we can't place foreground images.

To add a property in the property bar, we simple add the following code.

```
        [Browsable(true), Category("Custom controls"), Description("Background Image of Control")]
        //[EditorAttribute(typeof(UIFileNameEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
        //public UIBitmap UIBackImage
        public UIImageRes UIBackImage
        {
            get { return backImage;  }
            set { backImage = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
```

Now, to add a background image, we have this code

```
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint =
            System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode =
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode =
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode =
                System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;


            GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
            if (this.Is9Slice == UISlice.no && this.UIBackImage.UIImagePath != null  && this.UIBackImage.UIImagePath !="" )
            {

                Bitmap BgI = new Bitmap(this.backImage.UIImagePath);
                Rectangle dest = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
                Rectangle src = Rectangle.Empty;
                if (backImage.UIUVRectangle.Width * backImage.UIUVRectangle.Height != 0)
                {
                    src = backImage.UIUVRectangle;
                }
                else
                {
                    src= new Rectangle(0, 0, BgI.Width, BgI.Height);
                }
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BgI, dest, src, units);
                return;
            }
            if (this.UIBackImage.UIImagePath != null  && this.UIBackImage.UIImagePath != "")
            {
                Bitmap BgImage = new Bitmap(this.backImage.UIImagePath);
                Size BgI = new Size(UIBackImage.UIUVRectangle.Width, UIBackImage.UIUVRectangle.Height);
                Point Offset = new Point(UIBackImage.UIUVRectangle.X, UIBackImage.UIUVRectangle.Y);


                Rectangle dTopLeft, dTopCenter, dTopRight,   //Destination Rectangles
                          dMidLeft, dMidCenter, dMidRight,
                          dBottomLeft, dBottomCenter, dBottomRight;

                Rectangle sTopLeft, sTopCenter, sTopRight,   //Source Rectangles
                          sMidLeft, sMidCenter, sMidRight,
                          sBottomLeft, sBottomCenter, sBottomRight;

                int side_control;
                int side = side_control = (int)(BgI.Width < BgI.Height ? BgI.Width * 0.2f: BgI.Height * 0.2f);


                if (2 * side > this.Size.Width || 2 * side > this.Size.Height)
                    side_control = (int)(this.Width < this.Height ? this.Width / 2 : this.Height / 2);

                if (designScaleFactor != 1.0f)
                    side_control *= (int)designScaleFactor;


                dTopLeft = dTopCenter = dTopRight = dMidLeft = dMidCenter = dMidRight = dBottomLeft = dBottomCenter = dBottomRight = new Rectangle();
                sTopLeft = sTopCenter = sTopRight = sMidLeft = sMidCenter = sMidRight = sBottomLeft = sBottomCenter = sBottomRight = new Rectangle();

                /*  Top Left */
                dTopLeft.Location = new Point(0, 0);
                dTopLeft.Width = dTopLeft.Height = side_control;
                sTopLeft.Location = new Point(0 + Offset.X, 0 + Offset.Y ); // Just add the offset here for reflecting in every other rectangle
                sTopLeft.Width = sTopLeft.Height = side;

                /* Top Center */
                dTopCenter.Location = new Point(dTopLeft.Right, dTopLeft.Top);
                dTopCenter.Width = this.Width - 2 * side_control;
                dTopCenter.Height = dTopLeft.Height;
                sTopCenter.Location = new Point(sTopLeft.Right, sTopLeft.Top);
                sTopCenter.Width = BgI.Width - 2 * side;
                sTopCenter.Height = sTopLeft.Height;

                /* Top Right */
                dTopRight.Location = new Point(dTopCenter.Right, dTopCenter.Top);
                dTopRight.Width = dTopRight.Height = side_control;
                sTopRight.Location = new Point(sTopCenter.Right, sTopCenter.Top);
                sTopRight.Width = sTopRight.Height = side;

                /* Middle Top */
                dMidLeft.Location = new Point(dTopLeft.Left, dTopLeft.Bottom);
                dMidLeft.Width = dTopLeft.Width;
                dMidLeft.Height = this.Height - 2 * side_control;
                sMidLeft.Location = new Point(sTopLeft.Left , sTopLeft.Bottom );
                sMidLeft.Width = sTopLeft.Width;
                sMidLeft.Height = BgI.Height - 2 * side;

                /* Middle Center */
                dMidCenter.Location = new Point(dMidLeft.Right, dMidLeft.Top);
                dMidCenter.Width = this.Size.Width - 2 * side_control;
                dMidCenter.Height = this.Size.Height - 2 * side_control;
                sMidCenter.Location = new Point(sMidLeft.Right , sMidLeft.Top);
                sMidCenter.Width = BgI.Width - 2 * side;
                sMidCenter.Height = BgI.Height - 2 * side;

                /* Middle Right */
                dMidRight.Location = new Point(dMidCenter.Right, dMidCenter.Top);
                dMidRight.Width = side_control;
                dMidRight.Height = this.Size.Height - 2 * side_control;
                sMidRight.Location = new Point(sMidCenter.Right , sMidCenter.Top );
                sMidRight.Width = side;
                sMidRight.Height = BgI.Height - 2 * side;

                /* Bottom Left*/
                dBottomLeft.Location = new Point(dMidLeft.Left, dMidLeft.Bottom);
                dBottomLeft.Width = dBottomLeft.Height = side_control;
                sBottomLeft.Location = new Point(sMidLeft.Left , sMidLeft.Bottom );
                sBottomLeft.Width = sBottomLeft.Height = side;

                /* Bottom Center */
                dBottomCenter.Location = new Point(dBottomLeft.Right, dBottomLeft.Top);
                dBottomCenter.Width = this.Width - 2 * side_control;
                dBottomCenter.Height = side_control;
                sBottomCenter.Location = new Point(sBottomLeft.Right , sBottomLeft.Top );
                sBottomCenter.Width = BgI.Width - 2 * side;
                sBottomCenter.Height = side;

                /* Bottom Right */
                dBottomRight.Location = new Point(dBottomCenter.Right, dBottomCenter.Top);
                dBottomRight.Width = dBottomRight.Height = side_control;
                sBottomRight.Location = new Point(sBottomCenter.Right , sBottomCenter.Top );
                sBottomRight.Width = sBottomRight.Height = side;

                Image BG = (Image)BgImage;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dTopLeft, sTopLeft, units);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dTopCenter, sTopCenter, units);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dTopRight, sTopRight, units);

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dMidLeft, sMidLeft, units);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dMidCenter, sMidCenter, units);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dMidRight, sMidRight, units);

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dBottomLeft, sBottomLeft, units);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dBottomCenter, sBottomCenter, units);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(BG, dBottomRight, sBottomRight, units);

            }

        }
```

Now, my question is, which methods need to be overridden or written to get a foreground image as well?

Comment: Pretty unclear to me what "foreground image" is supposed to mean.  What's in the foreground is simply determined by the order in which you paint.  Whatever you draw last is on top.  Don't forget OnPaintBackground().

Comment: @HansPassant is there a significant difference between using `OnPaintBackground()` and just adding background painting to the `OnPaint()` method?

Comment: If you draw the complete control in OnPaint() then you have no use for OnPaintBackground().  You should stub it out so it doesn't do any unnecessary work.  Of course, you'd normally use it to do things like giving the BackColor and BackgroundImage properties a meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a foreground image property.  So taking your background image property as an example it would probably look something like this:

```
[Browsable(true), Category("Custom controls"), Description("Foreground Image of Control")]
public UIImageRes UIForeImage
{
    get { return foreImage;  }
    set { foreImage = value; Invalidate(); }
}
```

You will need to add the `foreImage` variable to the same place as the `backImage` (I guess these are private class variables).

Then you should add some sections to your `OnPaint` method to draw your foreground image.  Again you should look at how the background image is drawn and do something similar.  The order things are drawn is important and so it would be important to make sure that any foreground drawing is done *after* the background drawing (so that the foreground stuff is drawn on top).  Also note that if the foreground image is opaque and the same size as the background image then you won't see the background image because you will be drawing on top of it.

From what I can see, it looks like you will need to add these sections to your OnPaint method:

```
if (this.Is9Slice == UISlice.no && this.UIForeImage.UIImagePath != null  && this.UIForeImage.UIImagePath !="" )
{
    // Add foreground drawing code here
}

if (this.UIForeImage.UIImagePath != null  && this.UIForeImage.UIImagePath != "")
{
    // Add foreground drawing code here
}
```

This may be a good time to refactor the `OnPaint` method.  You could create separate methods for `PaintBackgroundImage(Graphics g)` and `PaintForegroundImage(Graphics g)`.  Or you might even be able to just use one method that can be used to draw both the background and foreground images, e.g. `PaintImage(Graphics g, UIImageRes image)`.  Then you would call these methods from within the OnPaint method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. I have refactored the code like you said. But, what I did was just change the variable names. I do not understand the code. What should I read to understand what's happening?

Comment: On the face of it there does seem to be a lot going on in the OnPaint method.  However, best to start with some simple tutorials and build on this knowledge.  I think the first thing to understand is the `Graphics` object.  It can be used to draw lots of different things on the screen including images.  Check [this tutorial](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/graphics/winforms-drawing-cs/) out and look for others using Google.  Then look in more detail at the [Graphics.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) method.